# Does Android 2.1 support HTTP streaming for mp3?

Tags: android, mp3

Does Android 2.1 support HTTP streaming for mp3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it supports mp3 streaming.

https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

**yes**, it support HTTP streaming. but https streaming is not supported in  Android 2.1.